# Kafka Streams state store exception when putting a value

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am using the low level processor API with state stores. Up to `0.10.0.1` it was working fine, but I have upgraded Kafka Streams and I am getting the below error. I figured out that this is due to the changelog and it is looking at the record context:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This should not happen as timestamp() should only be called while a record is processed
! at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.timestamp(AbstractProcessorContext.java:150)
! at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.StoreChangeLogger.logChange(StoreChangeLogger.java:60)
! at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:47)
! at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueStore.put(ChangeLoggingKeyValueStore.java:66)
! at     org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore$2.run(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:67)
```

---

```
@Override
    public void process(String arg0, List<Data> data {
        data.forEach((x) -> {
            String rawKey = x.getId();
            Data data = kvStore.get(rawKey);
            long bytesize = data == null ? 0 : data.getVolume();
            x.addVolume(bytesize);
            kvStore.put(rawKey, x);
        });
    }
  
public void start() {
        builder = new KStreamBuilder();
        storeSupplier =     Stores.create(getKVStoreName()).withKeys(getProcessorKeySerde()).withValues(getProcessorValueSerde()).persistent().build();
        builder.addStateStore(storeSupplier);
        stream = builder.stream(Serdes.String(), serde(),getTopicName());
        processStream(stream);
        streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, props);
        streams.cleanUp();
        streams.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        super.init(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.context.schedule(timeinterval);
        this.kvStore = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore(getKVStoreName());
    }
```

Comment: If I disabled the change log then this issue is not occurred. For Fail over this is not good :(

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Override
 public void process(String arg0, List<Data> data {
  data.forEach((x) -> {
   String rawKey = x.getId();
   Data data = kvStore.get(rawKey);
   long bytesize = val == null ? 0 : data.getVolume();
   x.addVolume(bytesize);
   kvStore.put(rawKey, x);
  });
 }

Comment: Hard to say... Did you try `0.10.2.1` -- it contains couple of bug fixes. Your brokers are also on `0.10.2`?

Comment: yes my broker is also on 0.10.2.0

Comment: You can upgrade you app without upgrading you broker. I would try it. (cf http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/upgrade-guide.html#compatibility)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exceptions like this may come up when using the *same* instance of the `Processor` across multiple streams threads or partitions.

Ensure that you are returning a new instance to the `ProcessorSupplier`:

```
new ProcesorSupplier(() -> new Processor(...
```

The same applies to `Transformer` and `TransformerSupplier` as well.

To broadly quote the documentation:

> Creating a single Processor/Transformer object and returning the same object reference in ProcesorSupplier/TransformerSupplier#get() would be a violation of the supplier pattern and leads to runtime exceptions.

Comment: A similar exception can be raised which is caused by the same thing: `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.` typically when a persistent statestore is involved, the producer writing to the changelog may raise this exception.